# GtkImageView sample of code

Tags: gtk

I want to use GtkImageView in my application, but i can't find some examples of code with using gtkimageview anywhere. Where can i see the sample?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `GtjImageView` in GTK+, I guess you meant `GtkIconView`.  There are two examples for the latter in `gtk-demo` program that comes with GTK+ itself.